# Firebase push item custom key

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I need push a object into the node followers but I don't found the way.

I try this:

```
this.af.database.list(`profile/${user}/followers/`).push({[from]: true});
```

But my output was this
[image]

I needs the next output

[image]

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `push()` will push a new node onto the list with an automatically generated random unique ID. If you need to set a specific value, you'll need to use `set()` instead:

```
this.af.database.object(`profile/${user}/followers/${from}`).set(true);
```

In this example, I'm using [`object()`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/objects.md) instead of `list()` to create a reference directly to the value in the list that you want to create, and where `${from}` is the same value as `[from]` in your code.

Alternatively, you could use the `update()` method instead:

```
this.af.database.object(`profile/${user}/followers`).update({[from]: true});
```

Comment: But, if i use set() this method deleted all data in followers and put true.

Comment: @MatiasCeliz You need to ensure you use `set()` on the `profile/${user}/followers/${from}` child where `${from}` is the ID you want to use. Don't use `set()` directly on the `followers` node.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can not understand you. I just need to insert a new element in the node Like the second image.
If I use this `this.af.database.list (` followers / $ {user} `) .push ({[from]: true});` my result is the first image. Then I tried `this.af.database.list (` followers / $ {user} `) set ({[from]: true});` and it works for an entry, if in the future you will need to add another follower this code replaces all the data in `followers / $ {user}` for the new user data

Comment: Yes, using my example should do what you want. You need to use `object()` instead of `list()` though. I've updated my answer.

Comment: This code works for me `this.af.database.object(`profile/${user}/followers`).update({[from]: true});` Thanks!